# How to use if statement in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a scheduling database in Microsoft Access. I have a table that has my orders in it and am using two different queries with if statements to calculate the estimated shipping date, i have 30 columns and between the two queries i am using `,IIf([engraving]>0,Date()+18,IIf([plating]>0,Date()+17`, and so on.....

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this in SQL because i have to union two different queries and i am getting duplicates even if i am not using union all.
Added more as requested:

```
SELECT IIf([BLAST]>0,Date()+18,IIf([Strip Cu-Ni]>0,Date()+18,IIf([Strip Hard Face]>0,Date()+17,IIf([Repair Determination]>0,Date()+16,IIf([Machine For Patch]>0,Date()+16,IIf([Fit Up]>0,Date()+15,IIf([EB Weld]>0,Date()+15,IIf([Bader]>0,Date()+14,IIf([Local Straightening]>0,Date()+13,IIf([Hot Die]>0,Date()+12,IIf([Vapor Hone]>0,Date()+11))))))))))) AS [Estimated Ship Date], [Front End Classic].[CUSTOMER NAME], [Front End Classic].Priority, [Front End Classic].FAMILY, [Front End Classic].[PO#], [Front End Classic].[DATE RECEIVED], [Front End Classic].Priority, [Front End Classic].qty, [Front End Classic].Blast, [Front End Classic].[Strip Cu-Ni], [Front End Classic].[Strip Hard Face], [Front End Classic].CMM, [Front End Classic].[Repair Determination], [Front End Classic].UT, [Front End Classic].[Machine For Patch], [Front End Classic].[Fit Up], [Front End Classic].[EB Weld], [Front End Classic].Bader, [Front End Classic].[Local Straightening], [Front End Classic].[Hot Die], [Front End Classic].[Vapor Hone], [Front End Classic].[Prep Shroud], [Front End Classic].[Weld Shroud], [Front End Classic].[Prep Tip], [Front End Classic].[Weld Tip], [Front End Classic].[Mill Tip], [Front End Classic].[Mill Shroud], [Front End Classic].Blend, [Front End Classic].[Stress Relief], [Front End Classic].FPI, [Front End Classic].[X-Ray], [Front End Classic].PEEN, [Front End Classic].ECI, [Front End Classic].HVOF, [Front End Classic].Vibro, [Front End Classic].[CU-NI], [Front End Classic].Seals, [Front End Classic].[Moly Dag]
FROM [Front End Classic]
WHERE (((IIf([BLAST]>0,Date()+18,IIf([Strip Cu-Ni]>0,Date()+18,IIf([Strip Hard Face]>0,Date()+17,IIf([Repair Determination]>0,Date()+16,IIf([Machine For Patch]>0,Date()+16,IIf([Fit Up]>0,Date()+15,IIf([EB Weld]>0,Date()+15,IIf([Bader]>0,Date()+14,IIf([Local Straightening]>0,Date()+13,IIf([Hot Die]>0,Date()+12,IIf([Vapor Hone]>0,Date()+11)))))))))))) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: I consider case constructs to be easier than iif functions.

Comment: Please post more of your query and not a snippet line. And what do you mean *easier way*? Are you receiving the results desired but do not want too many nested `IIF()`?

Comment: I am getting the results I need except there are too many nested if statements so I have to break it up to 2 queries and use the union, When I do that sometimes I get duplicates because one order will be within both queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would explore using the Switch function, which would be a lot cleaner. I.e.

Date() + SWITCH([Strip Cu-Ni]>0, 18, [Strip Hard Face]>0, 17, etc) As [EstimatedShipDate]

Note that the first condition that evaluates to true, reading left to right, will resolve the switch and it will exit.

In all honesty, it looks like your data model is not designed well to give you what you need, but you may not have the luxury of changing that. :-)

Hope it helps...

Comment: thank you for your help and any constructive criticism you can give me helps. I do have the luxury of doing what I want with the data, I am just not educated enough yet with access to know better ways of doing it.

Comment: That has worked very well  and is definitely a lot cleaner thank you!!!!!

Comment: Awesome Gianni. Please ping me if you hit any additional issues.